# MySQL Select max() from every Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, greatest-n-per-group

I there a way to get the `max()` Value of every Value?
I have a table like this:

```
id primary key
name foreign key
age
```

and I need the highes age of every Name. For example:

```
ID  NAME   AGE
1,  Marco, 12
2,  Jason, 23
3,  Tom,   5
4,  Marco, 16
5,  Jason, 22
```

The output should be:

```
ID  NAME   AGE
2,  Jason, 23
3,  Tom,   5
4,  Marco, 16
```

Is this possible and how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the max value of each column using aggregation:

```
select max(id), name, max(age)
from t
group by name;
```

But if you want the complete row with the max age, then that would be:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.age = (select max(t2.age) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Comment: For completeness, it's worth noting that this (excellent) answer will give you multiple results for a name in any case where you have a tie for oldest with that name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id,name,max(age) over(partition by name) as max_age from table group by id,name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select min(id) id, name, max(age) age from mytable group by name
```

Comment: `min(id)` would give them `1` for `'Marco'` instead of `4` as in the desired result.

Comment: @stickybit: yes. But `max(id)` gives `5` for Jason instead of  `2`!

Comment: I think they neither wanted `min(id)` nor `max(id)` but the `id` of the record(s) with the maximum age.

Comment: @stickybit: I think you're right. And the accepted answer offers a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `max age` and `name` from sub query then left join to obtain its `ID`.

```
SELECT b.id, a.name, a.maxage
FROM (SELECT name, MAX(age) AS maxage
FROM table
GROUP BY NAME
) a
LEFT JOIN table b ON a.NAME = b.NAME AND a.maxage= b.AGE
```